# How to remap shortcut in Powershell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to remap the shortcut in powershell, for example, I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to make cursor at beginning of line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to make cursor at the end of line, etc.

I searched the method in Google for long time, but it seems no one did that before. Any one can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you talk about powershell.exe console?
You can define it with PSConsoleHostReadLine function with PowerShell "3.0"

see here.
http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2012/09/13/bash-like-tab-completion-in-powershell/

Comment: Please provide more details on how to use the PSConsoleHostReadLine function. Not everyone is a PowerShell expert.

Comment: Excuse me Microsoft PowerShell team don't try to make the document, you should request it to them, not to me...

Comment: @hoge sorry if you misunderstood. On Super User we prefer answers to give sufficient information to solve the problem (or at least get a good start) without having to go hunting for further resources. If you need to link to another site (or just provide the name of a function), we would prefer that you add some information summarizing _how_ to do it. As a question and answer site, we're focused on providing complete answers, not just serving as a link portal to other sites. This is partially because links often die over time, and we also like to give a full answer. Thanks, and welcome!

Comment: @hoge Version of my powershell is 3.0, I will have some investigation about *PSConsoleHostReadLine* which you mentiond. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the PSReadline module pretty cool!! But, there some bugs in there, so I cannot use this module because of specific prompt. But it works!! Thanks @hoge

Comment: @nhinkle sorry but PSConsoleHostReadLine is very primitive, so I can't show meaningful sample script on this board. it become very very long sample script.

Comment: @Marslo if you can hack scripts, I suggest WindowsKeyBinding  [link](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WindowsKeyBinding-for-60fb0d55).
At readline.psm1 line 1564: $Handler.Control('A', $function:SelectAll) to $Handler.Control('A', $function:CmdHome)

Comment: @hoge Well, hack... I'm just a new user, :). But I think I will have a try if I can. By the way, I'v fixed this problem, using AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 5):

Powershell v 5.0 includes PSReadLine.

Use these commands for the desired beavior (Ctrl-A, Ctrl-E, Ctrl-K, Ctrl-U behave like in a bash shell):

```
Import-Module PSReadLine
Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Emacs
```

Source:
https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine

Comment: Great exactly what I was looking for having recently converted from Mac und using Bash for Windows, this brings the three worlds close together!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are now 2 versions of PSReadline.  The original version (referred to in the accepted answer) is not maintained and does have some bugs.

A more fully featured and actively maintained version is described here:

http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/psreadline-a-better-line-editing-experience-for-the-powershell-console/

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I've re-map the shortcut by [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  I will try.